# при попытке забанить человека в телеграм выдаёт ошибку. aiogram, python

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

```
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True, commands=["бан"], commands_prefix="!/")
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply("это должен быть ответ на сообщение")
        return

    await message.bot.delete_message(message.message_id, chat_id=config.GROUP_ID)
    await message.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id) 

    await message.reply_to_message.reply("пользователь наказан!")
```

пишу !бан и выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
iogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py:409> exception=TypeError("delete_message() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'")>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 417, in _process_polling_updates
    for responses in itertools.chain.from_iterable(await self.process_updates(updates, fast)):
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 238, in process_updates
    return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\dispatcher.py", line 259, in process_update
    return await self.message_handlers.notify(update.message)
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\aiogram\dispatcher\handler.py", line 116, in notify
    response = await handler_obj.handler(*args, **partial_data)
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\Desktop\Модератор\bot.py", line 22, in cmd_ban
    await message.bot.delete_message(message.message_id, chat_id=config.GROUP_ID)
TypeError: delete_message() got multiple values for argument 'chat_id'
```

Comment: Возможно, у вас перепутаны параметры при вызове `delete_message`. Попробуйте поменять местами, убрав `chat_id=`, или добавьте `message_id=`.

Comment: смотрите в документации правильный порядок: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/dev-3.x/api/bot.html#aiogram.client.bot.Bot.delete_message

Comment: Плюс ещё вы можете удалять сообщение и блокировать пользователя одновременно, а не последовательно. Воспользуйтесь функцией [asyncio.gather](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну во-первых, чтобы удалить сообщение:

```py
await message.delete()
```

Во-вторых, забанить пользователя нужно так:

```py
await bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
```

Итог:

```py
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True, commands=["бан"], commands_prefix="!/")
async def cmd_ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply("это должен быть ответ на сообщение")
        return

    await bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat.id, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
    await message.delete()

    await message.reply_to_message.reply("пользователь наказан!")
```

Comment: тогда получается это:  aiogram.utils.exceptions.ChatNotFound: Chat not found

Comment: Обновил ответ, попробуйте сейчас

Comment: не-а 

> python bot.py
  File "C:\Users\Tonix\Desktop\Модератор\bot.py", line 22
    await bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=message.chat,id, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
                                                                                                     ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: Точку забыл :) ещё раз

Comment: спасибо, теперь работает

Comment: Не за что, рад помочь